# How to Remove Excess Whitespace in String Using Regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a series of paragraphs that I want to parse using regular expressions, but unfortunately, the paragraph is appearing with many white spaces in between sentences, and sometimes words. I would like to be able to remove all excess white space, but I'm unsure how... Anyone have any ideas? I don't want to remove all whitespace, which is the only thing I've found so far, but to keep regular paragraph format, as in after every word have a white space, and after every punctuation+word have a whitespace. I am coding in Perl.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Canonicalize horizontal whitespace:

```
s/\h+/ /g;
```

Canonicalize vertical whitespace:

```
s/\v+/\n/g;
```

Canonicalize all whitespace:

```
s/[\h\v]+/ /g;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the simple perl regex

```
s/\s+/ /g;
```

FYI, this sort of thing is best done with the unix tool [`tr`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/tr/)

```
tr -s ' '
```

Will *squeeze* spaces to a single space.

Comment: Perl has tr/// too: tr/\n\r\f\t / /s

Answer (score 1):

Both the above answers are giving the result, but in both cases, a space is there in the beginning and end of the string.

If I use these regex on string **"   hello   world      "**, I am getting the answer as **" hello world "**

To get the result as **"hello world"**, the following perl regex will work fine

```
$a =~ s/(?<!\w) //g;
```

Using the look-behind here, all extra spaced are removed.