# Manual change of one attribute dependant on another before updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am following this guidance over here: [Update params in Ruby on Rails controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640557/update-params-in-ruby-on-rails-controller)
... but it's not entirely working. Full code of my "update" method in the corresponding controller below - but what is happening is that

- the FIRST time I go into the form and change "my_bool_attr" to false, "my_int_attr" does not change
- the SECOND time I go into the form and do NOTHING (my_bool_attr already shows as false/unticked, my_int_attr still shows the previous value) but submit - my_int_attr gets set to 0

Same the other way round: if my_bool_attr is false and I tick it on (and enter a number for my_int_attr), my_bool_attr reflects properly as TRUE but my_int_attr doesn't change. I have to go to the form AGAIN and set the number for my_int_attr again - then it updates in the database.

Why do I have to go through this routine twice? Thank you!

My controller's update method:

```
def update

    attributes = model_params.clone

    attributes[:my_int_attr] = 0 unless @my_model.my_bool_attr

    if @my_model.update(attributes)
      redirect_to @my_model, notice: "Update was was successful."
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

EDIT: FULL CODE:
Here is the full schema of the DB as per db/schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_05_17_135523) do

  create_table "movies", charset: "utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "runtime"
    t.integer "release_year"
    t.integer "rating"
    t.boolean "seen"
    t.string "file_path"
    t.string "poster"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "sort_title"
    t.string "hr_poster"
  end

end
```

Here is the full view partial (the form); it has some placeholders for later additions (actor checkboxes, genre checkboxes, and what I call "movie-groups" - which will be a way to sort movies into different groups by the user), don't worry about these :)

```
<%= form_with(model: movie) do |form| %>
  <% if movie.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(movie.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this movie from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% movie.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 border-end pe-2">

        <div class="row mb-3 align-items-center form-group">
            <div class="col-2"><%= form.label :title, class: 'form-label mb-0' %></div>
            <div class="col"><%= form.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', id: 'input_title' %></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mb-3 align-items-center form-group">
            <div class="col-2"><%= form.label :sort_title, class: 'form-label' %></div>
            <div class="col"><%= form.text_field :sort_title, class: 'form-control' %></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mb-3 align-items-center form-group">
            <div class="col-2"><%= form.label :runtime, class: 'form-label mb-0' %></div>
            <div class="col"><%= form.number_field :runtime, class: 'form-control' %></div>
            <div class="col-2"><%= form.label :release_year, class: 'form-label mb-0' %></div>
            <div class="col"><%= form.number_field :release_year, class: 'form-control' %></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-3 align-items-center form-group">
            <div class="col">
                Studio Select
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-3 align-items-center form-group">
            <div class="col-2"><%= form.label :poster, class: 'form-label mb-0' %></div>
            <div class="col"><%= form.text_field :poster, class: 'form-control' %></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-3 align-items-center form-group">
            <div class="col-2"><%= form.label :hr_poster, class: 'form-label mb-0' %></div>
            <div class="col"><%= form.text_field :hr_poster, class: 'form-control' %></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-3 align-items-center form-group">
            Moviegroup Select
        </div>


        <div class="row mb-3 align-items-center form-group">
            <div class="col-2 form-check form-switch"><%= form.check_box :seen, class: 'form-check-input' %> <%= form.label :seen, class: 'form-check-label' %></div>
            <div class="col-2"><%= form.label :rating, class: 'form-label mb-0' %></div>
            <div class="col"><%= form.number_field :rating, class: 'form-control' %></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row align-items-center mb-3 me-1">
            <h4>Actors</h4>
            <div class="mb-3 form-check actor_box border border-2 form-group">
                Actors Checkboxes
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4>Genre</h4>
        <div class="mb-3 form-check genre_box border border-2 form-group">
          Genre Checkboxes
        </div>
        <p><%= @movie.poster ? image_tag(@movie.poster, class: 'rounded movie_poster_form') : raw("<span class='float-start nopic'>X</span>") %></p>
    </div>

    </div>


<div class="row align-items-center mt-3">
    <div class="col mb-3 actions"><%= form.submit class: 'btn btn-outline-primary' %></div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

And here is the full controller code. The

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_movie, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  before_action :all_movies

  # GET /movies
  def index
    @pagy, @movies = pagy(Movie.order(:sort_title))
  end

  # GET /movies/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /movies/new
  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
  end

  # GET /movies/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /movies
  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)

    if @movie.sort_title.length == 0
      @movie.sort_title = create_sort_title(@movie.title)
    end

    # The HR Version of the Poster is the same as the low-res one - but stops after the "_V1_" part of the string

    if @movie.poster?
      @movie.hr_poster = @movie.poster.gsub(/_V1_.*/,'.jpg')
    end

    if !@movie.seen?
      @movie.rating = 0
    end

    if @movie.save
      redirect_to @movie, notice: "Movie was successfully created."
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /movies/1
  def update

    attributes = movie_params.clone

    attributes = attributes.merge(rating: 0) if !@movie.seen

    if @movie.update(attributes)
      redirect_to @movie, notice: "Movie was successfully updated."
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /movies/1
  def destroy
    @movie.destroy
    redirect_to movies_url, notice: "Movie was successfully removed."
  end


  private

    def create_sort_title(current_title)
      # The Regex is case-insensitive and looks for any string beginning with the, a, an (followed by a space) and replaces with "nothing"
      # then it removes any special characters
      # and finally it removes excess whitespace (found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846638/how-to-remove-excess-whitespace-in-string-using-regex)
      @sortable_title = current_title.gsub(/^the | a | an /i, '').gsub(/'|"|!|\?|-/, '').gsub(/(?<!\w) /,'')
    end

    # get all movies - needed in all sidebars
    def all_movies
      @all_movies = Movie.order(:sort_title)
    end

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_movie
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def movie_params
      params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :sort_title, :runtime, :release_year, :rating, :seen, :file_path, :poster, :hr_poster)
    end
end
```

asdf

Answer (score 1):

The attributes var is not being updating. Try with this code

```
def update
  attributes = model_params.clone
  attributes = attributes.merge(my_int_attr: 0) if !@my_model.my_bool_attr
  if @my_model.update(attributes)
    redirect_to @my_model, notice: "Update was was successful."
  else
    render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Comment: Aha interesting! Would you help me to understand this? I mean why is the var not being updated? I suspect this is pretty basic ruby hash coding...? But then why is it working when i run the method the second time?

Comment: OK so I tried the above with attributes.merge. It doesn't work - or rather, same behaviour as previously... it updates only when I open the form a SECOND time. :(

Comment: Maybe you have something weird in your view or in your model. What params are sent in the first and second try?

Comment: So when I look at the server's console, it definitively only sends the my_bool_attr param in the first round, and then in the second try, it sends both my_bool_attr as well as my_int_attr.

Comment: Also I just checked.... my view has nothing weird I think. It's a simple form with some bootstrap css...

Comment: In my controller, the only unusual thing is a method that fetches all elements of my model and displays them in a sidebar (with a "before: " action). I just removed that method - still the same problem. I set my_bool_attr to false - my_int_attr is not updated. I go again EITHER set my_bool_attr back to true OR do not touch anything - and NOW my_int_attr is set to 0 (??) ...

Comment: Its hard for me to identify the error without see the code. You can update the question with some screenshots of your model, controller and view and i will take a look. Another thing i think could be happening its in your migration, Have you set a default value to this attr?

Comment: It's a very simple movie DB (which I am trying to program to get into Rails :) ... I have added the full code of the controller, the view (a form partial), as well as the db schema above. My_int_attr corresponds to "rating" (where movies can be rated, 1-10), my_bool_attr corresponds to "seen" (is the movie seen or not - rating shall only be possible if seen)